# How do I remove one component from Microsoft Office?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office-2007

I have Microsoft Office 2007 installed, and I would like to remove PowerPoint, and keep the rest.  I'm on Windows XP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have Microsoft Office installed on your XP Professional machine and you want to remove individual programs or components from it, you can do so through the **`"Add/Remove Programs"`** utility. This utility, when used properly, will let you remove the exact component you want to delete while leaving the rest of the Office XP Professional suite intact.

1. Close all open programs on your computer. Click the "**`Start`**" button, open the "**`Control Panel`**" and open "**`Add/Remove Programs.`**".
2. Click the "**`Change or Remove Programs`**" button, `wait for Microsoft Office` to appear in the installed programs list, click on it and then click the "**`Change`**" button.
3. Click "**`Add or Remove Features`**," click "**`Next`**" and then use the ***`"+"`*** symbol next to each component and program to expand them and select which ones you want installed and ***`which you want removed.`***
4. Click "**`Upgrade`**" or "**`Continue`**" to apply the settings you selected. Restart your computer when this process is finished.

For more information, Have a look at the Microsoft help questions: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/install-or-remove-individual-office-programs-and-components-HA001234067.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Control Panel, then Software / Programs (depending on which Windows version), find Microsoft Office in the list of installed programs and then right-click on it, you should be presented with the option to "Change" which parts of Office you have installed!

Answer (score 0):

Run MS Office installer and choose Repair option.